# Set Visible property of div with an inline-tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set the Visible property of a div with runat='server' attribute, directly from the code in the page, by calling a function in the code behind, but it seems the code is not evaluated at all by the server. 
The code looks like this

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsInRole("User") %>'>
```

Where 'IsInRole' is a protected function on the page that return a bool.

Many Thanks

FOUND SOLUTION:

```
<% if (IsInRole("Administrator")){%>
    <div id="mydiv">Admin content here</div>
<% }%>
```

Comment: It could be cool if people could leave a comment about why they downvote a question ... especialy when it's new people and when it's written to do it when downvoting...

Answer (score 2):

As the div is runat="server" you should be able to access it from code behind something like this in pageload:

mydiv.Visible = IsInRole(User);

(If IsInRole returns true or false)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use code-behind for this property becausse when I need to change the value of the Role variable, I can do it without recompiling the project but simply changing it in the page

Comment: asp.net apps doesn't need compiling..the code-behind will automatically compile at runtime @Edika

Comment: That's not true. The web apps with code behind need to be compiled prior to be deployed. The code behind is compiled into an assembly deployed with the pages. @Nitinjs

Comment: Yes, but if you are using xcopy then it doesn't need compiling

Answer (score 1):

In

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" Visible='<%# IsInRole("User") %>'>
```

# indicates a databinding, and its content will be evaluated only at the moment the databinding is done. So first, be sure, your control is databound during the execution of the page, and secondly that your value is correctly evaluated at that time.

otherwise you might prefer

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" Visible='<%= IsInRole("User") %>'>
```

Where your espression will be evaluated on every execution of the page.

see [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx) for further details

Comment: This is not allowed in server Tag, thanks anyway. I've found an alternative solution